# Lambda black magic taking different types

Tags: c++, lambda, auto

Trying to find yet another way to simply serialize my code, I had the stupid idea to try this impossible thing. But it worked. I really wonder why:

```
template <typename C>
void f(C c)
{
    int a = 1;
    float b = 1.5f;
    c(a);
    c(b);
}

int main()
{
    f([](auto v){
        std::cerr << v << "\n";
    });
    return 0;
}
```

I looked at the resulting assembly (g++-9.3 -O0 -g -S -fverbose-asm test.cpp -o test.s), and it appears that two distincts lambdas are generated: one taking a float, and the other one taking an int. Is this black magic? Is there anyone who knows the standard and can explain more about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This call:

```
f([](auto v){
        std::cerr << v << "\n";
    });
```

is passing a generic lambda to `f`, as the argument `c`. A generic lambda is one that has a templated member `operator()`, because of the `auto` parameter.

So when you make the following calls:

```
c(a);  // int argument
c(b);  // float argument
```

the compiler will instantiate one version of the lambda's member `operator()` with `int`, and one version of the member `operator()` with `float`.

Comment: Ok, so we can see the lambda as template function, instantiated at callsites. Interesting... and powerfull.

Comment: @etham Pretty much, except as mentioned in the answer, the lambda is not a template, but the `operator()` member is.

Answer (score 10):

A generic lambda is mostly similar to

```
struct lambda
{
    template <typename T>
    auto operator()(T v) const
    {
        std::cerr << v << "\n";
    }
// ...
};
```

The lambda itself is not a template, but its member `operator()` is.

Comment: I do like the explanation being phrased as a syntax rewrite, but since C++20 made both `void f(auto) {...}` and `auto f = []<typename T>(T) {...}` valid, I'm finding it trickier to do that :(

Comment: @cigien: I would say it allows even more similitude, as for `[]<std::size_t ... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {}`. I would say c++ logic (with verbosity) would want second syntax, simplified to the former (as it is for regular template functions with concept syntax).